# Event triggered Window Message

Tags: winapi, overlapped-io

Is there a way to generate a Window message when an Event is set?  I want to setup an overlapped I/O operation, so it is not blocking, but I would like not to poll its status.  I know I can use a thread, but I would only need it for this operation.  There seems like there is a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably do that, but what Windows supports more directly is using `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects`, which will return when you get a message, *or* any of the handles you pass (which can be only one) is signaled.

Alternatively, you could use `ReadFileEx`/`WriteFileEx` to do the I/O, and use `MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx`. In this case, you specify a completion routine. Execution jumps directly from your call to `MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx` to your completion routine, without your having to look at messages/return values to figure out what happened, then jump to the code to deal with it appropriately.

Either way, you continue to process other Windows messages and deal with completion of the I/O, without polling for I/O completion.